# Latex Layout Subfigure Problem - remove lines

Tags: graphics, layout

I am a total LateX newbie and I encountered a problem, which i could'nt solve for the past 2 days.

For my thesis I want 3 figures arranged in the same way. I played around with some code snippets and LateX templates and I was able to display it like this (which is fine for me).

However, whatever I try I cannot get rid of the 3 vertical lines in the figure.

I tried adding serveral packages, but none of them worked (i left them in the code for now on).[image]
Oh and :and is it possible that the caption font is bigger than the subcaption ones?

I appreciate your help :)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,sf},font={small, sf},
labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage[format=plain,margin=3cm]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{5}{5}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25, left]{hiking}
\caption{Migration pattern and habitat preferences} 
\end{subfigure}
&
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \smallskip 
    \smallskip 
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright}
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, right ]{ele}
            \caption{elevation profile}
        \end{flushright}
        \end{subfigure}\\
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \hspace{3 cm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, right]{graph2}
            \caption[left] {migration distance in\\ regard to precipitation}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{tabular}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption*{Migration pattern of BP61}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In the outer tabular preamble (line 6 of your code), just replace `{|c|c|}` with `{cc}`

Comment: I didn't expect the problem to be that simple. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome! I wonder whether using two minipages side by side wouldn't have led to a simpler code.

Comment: I tried the minipage approach as well, but i had trouble aligning me figures there..
Well i am thankful it worked now.
Is there any chance that the caption appears bigger than the subcaption in my figure ?

Comment: Do you mean  the global caption bigger tha each individual subcaption? You can try `\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize}`.